# FL Chart vertical dotted lines independent from dots

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

I am using [FLChart](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/line_chart.md) in my app to display some charts. That is working just fine. However I would like to be able to draw some vertical dotted lines into my graph like this:

[image]

As you can see, some of them should also have Numbers on top of them. Ive searched for quite some time now but could not find anything like this.

I found somehting similar looking on their [example](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/line_chart/samples/line_chart_sample5.dart) :

[image]

But it is not quite the same. The lines should be independent from any dots. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
You can draw vertical dotted line with this code snippet. Line chart data has property named extraLinesData. You can use it like below. 

 return LineChartData(
 extraLinesData: ExtraLinesData(verticalLines: <VerticalLine>[
        VerticalLine(x: 2, color: Constants.PRIMARY_COLOR_1, dashArray: [4,4]),
      ],) ...,
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your goal correctly, you simply want to get the result of the given example except for the dots for each data point.

You can get rid of the points by changing the `FlDotData` passed to the `TouchedSpotIndicatorData`. Going back to the example code you linked, you could replace:

```dart
FlDotData(
  show: true,
  getDotPainter: (spot, percent, barData, index) =>
      FlDotCirclePainter(
    radius: 8,
    color: lerpGradient(
      barData.colors,
      barData.colorStops!,
      percent / 100,
    ),
    strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeColor: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```

with:

```dart
FlDotData(
  show: false,
)
```

Comment: sorry if I was unclear. My graph should still show some points. But on top of that there should be some lines, but they don't have anything to do with the dots on the graph

Comment: the lines should simply be vertical lines on some x-values

Comment: Okay, sorry, then I was wrong. The `FlLine` seems to be drawn only up to the respective y-value. Not sure whether another functionality exists that supports drawing vertical lines across the entire chart for certain x-values. You could of course clone the repo and adjust the code to your needs. In this specific example, it seems that you would have to change the line 336 from `final lineEndY = min(data.maxY, max(data.minY, data.lineTouchData.getTouchLineEnd(barData, index)));` to `final lineEndY = data.maxY` in the `line_chart_painter.dart` file.